# How do I add a maximum column count and expand windows in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

What I am trying to do is create a GUI in Python with checkboxes and have it print the selections the user makes.  This code works:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

color_list = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple']

layout = [
    [sg.Column(
        [[sg.Checkbox(item, key=item)] for item in color_list],
        justification='left',

    )],
    [sg.Button('Submit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Select Colors You Like', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
        
    if event == 'Submit':
        #create list for checked colors
        selected_colors = [item for item in color_list if values[item]]
        break

print(selected_colors)

window.close()
```

The issues I can't figure out are twofold:

- A problem comes if I make my list very long — I would like to have this scale to perhaps 4 or 5 checkbox items per row rather than one row with everything.  How do I do this?
- How do I make the window scale to the title of the window?  In the this case, because of the length of the selections, the window title "Select Colors You Like" doesn't show.  How do I fix this so the window scales to the title size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A problem comes if I make my list very long — I would like to have this scale to perhaps 4 or 5 checkbox items per row rather than one row with everything. How do I do this?

Following code demo the way how I do it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

number = 9
column_layout, line = [], []
limit = len(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST) - 1
for i, image in enumerate(sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST):
    line.append(sg.Image(data=image, size=(64, 64), pad=(1, 1), background_color='#10C000', expand_y=True, key=f'IMAGE {i}'))
    if i % number == number-1 or i == limit:
        column_layout.append(line)
        line = []

layout = [[sg.Column(column_layout)]]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

> How do I make the window scale to the title of the window? In the this case, because of the length of the selections, the window title "Select Colors You Like" doesn't show. How do I fix this so the window scales to the title size?

You can do it by add option `size` to the Checkbox element, like `size=30` in your case.

[image]